# How can a Sonar widget show a project level property?

Tags: sonarqube

I am attempting to display a project level property on a widget.  Global properties work fine, but project properties come up blank.

I am using:

```
<%= configuration('sonar.projectlevel.prop1') -%>
```

in the .erb file, where sonar.projectlevel.prop1 is property name.  It comes up blank.  If I put in a global property instead of the project property,the property is displayed.

When I open the project dashboard and go into Configuration | Settings, I can see the project property and the value.  I can also retrieve it using the ws properties api specifying the resource name, so the value must be there.

Should this work?  If so, how?

I have also posted this question to the mailing, but have not had a response.  Surely this can work and is easy to do.  I must be missing something simple.

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon Brandhof replied to [the mailing list question](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Widget-access-to-project-properties-tt5023207.html) with the solution.  To display a project level property in a widget use:

```
Property.value('sonar.projectlevel.prop1', @project.id)
```

instead of:

```
configuration('sonar.projectlevel.prop1')
```

Thanks Simon!